# Anonymous GET request pings Telegram Bot heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telepot

I have created a Telegram Bot using TELEPOT which is deployed on heroku. It works fine but, never goes to sleep. Because I am using free service which gives 550Hours a month. I want my app to go idle.
But, after every 30mins I get these GET Requests.

[Heroku Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL0FX.png)

My app does not handle GET request so it gives 405 response code.

Now is there any way to stop that anonymous ping or If is there any way to block all GET requests before it pings my SERVER?

Here is my code:

https://github.com/SagunDevkota/pythonanywhere-app/tree/main